# creating an array without declaring its size, in a class c++

Tags: c++, arrays

When I create an array without declaring its size in class, it doesn't give any error
it works fine but why? this happens only inside the class, when I do same in my main function it gives error.

```
class B {
private:
     char array[]; 
public:
    ///.....///
};
```

Comment: You still have to `new` it somewhere or assign it values

Comment: The "C++" way to do this is `std::vector`...

Comment: I want to know why it works?

Comment: It works because your compiler supports it even though it's not standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that your compiler implements flexible array members (a C language feature) as an extension to C++.

Compiling your program with standard compliance enabled, produces these diagnostics:

clang:

```
main.cpp:3:11: error: flexible array member 'array' in otherwise empty class is a GNU extension [-Werror,-Wgnu-empty-struct]
     char array[]; 
          ^
main.cpp:3:11: error: flexible array members are a C99 feature [-Werror,-Wc99-extensions]
```

gcc:

```
test.cc:3:17: error: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'array' [-pedantic]
```

IBM:

```
"test.cc", line 3.11: 1540-2887 (S) A flexible array member is not permitted in this scope.
```

Oracle:

```
"test.cc", line 3: Error: In this declaration "array" is of an incomplete type "char[]".
```

PS: note that the way you're using it would be an error in C as well: you need at least one named member before the flexible

Comment: in main function it gives error but in class it doesn't, why is this so?

Comment: @Bramsh The above errors were generated at line 3 of your example (in class). If you're using something like gcc, remember to enable standard compliance with `--pedantic-errors`

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a requirement of your program, then I suggest using a `std::vector` because of its "flexibility" and performance. You will not have to worry about the question you've just asked here:

```
class B
{
private:
    std::vector<char> array;
public:
    ///......///
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, which is *why* the given situation doesn't result in an error

Answer (score 0):

First, an array with an empty size is non-standard.  That same code will not compile with an ANSI C++ conforming compiler.

What you are probably using is a compiler with this extension of allowing empty array declarations (probably gcc / g++).  Turn off the extensions, and you will get a compiler error.

To get around this issue, use a container such as std::vector.